# JSX loading Images as they are generated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, dynamic, jsx

I am working on a project which generates images. I am using JSX for a React app. I need to load images dynamically as they are generated (Loading one after the other on the Images page). Currently, I have a function called getImages. It awaits for a response from my Flask app which, when returned, means that the logos are generated and are in the right spot (I think what will happen when I run this is that it will wait for both images to load, but I haven't been able to get anything to display, even with both images in the right folder). Once I get that response, the functions inside getImages are returning Card objects (which are just simple wrappers for an . I have tried useEffect, and a button click listener, but they don't seem to be working. Here is my code for the getImages function.

```
    async function getImage1(){
        const response= await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/img1")
        const data = await response.json();
        return (
        <Card image="my_path/output/img1.jpg"/>
        )
    }

    async function getImage2(){
      const response= await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/img1")
      const data = await response.json();
      return (
      <Card image="my_path/output/img2.jpg"/>
      )
      }
    getImage1();
    getImage2()
  }
```

Here is my code for wat my page returns:

```
useEffect(getImages)

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={e => getImages}>GetImages</button>
        {getImages()}
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default Images;
```

I really appreciate the help that you all provide, so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you fetching the image and not doing anything with the data?
I think you should save the fetch images in a components state. Or just the url of the images, and then in the return do:

```
   return(
      <>
          {images.map(imageUrl => <Card img={imageUrl}/>)}
      </>
   )
```

Also have a read to the docs of the useEffect function specifically the second argunemnt param 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting Image Generator

```
const App = () => {
  const [hash,setHash] = useState(0)
  return (
    <div>
        <Component hash={hash}/>
        <button onClick={()=>setHash(Math.random() * 100) + 1}>Generate Image</button>
        </div>
  )
}

const Component = ({hash}) => {  
const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const [image,setImage] = useState('')
console.log(hash)
useEffect(()=>{
  fetch(`https://robohash.org/${hash}`)
    .then(response=>response.blob())
    .then(image => {      
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(image)
      setImage(url)
      setIsLoading(false)
  })
},[hash])


return(
  isLoading ? 'Loading...' :
    <div>
      <img src={image}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```